# Pagination with Select Query - PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have this piece of code that basically within the same if loop, performs two select, in order to implement two bottons that give the user the possibility of being able to navigate between a successive record and a previous one, so far nothing strange, if not that in the actual navigation, the user finds problems in the navigation because often the order that is followed is not linear, admitting that there are 4 records to scroll:

a, b, c, d

right now this code from this behavior,

a, b, a, c, a, d, c

and this is not good, the two queries are completely the same, they differ only from the previous and subsequent option precisely to allow what I wrote before, I tried to change the parameters of equality but the result remains such, what could I do?

```
if($_GET['te']==""){
        $sel_tipo_acc = 0;
    }else{
        $sel_tipo_acc = $_GET['te'];
    }

    if($_GET['fe'] != "S"){

    $mystr_record_precedente = "-1";
    if (isset($id_str)) {
      $mystr_record_precedente = $id_str;
    }
    $myte_record_precedente = "-1";
    if (isset($sel_tipo_acc)) {
      $myte_record_precedente = $sel_tipo_acc;
    }
    //42320819($database_riskmanagement, $riskmanagement);
    $query_record_precedente = sprintf("SELECT * FROM tev_Evidenze AS ev LEFT JOIN tev_Fatt_crit AS fc ON fc.ID_fatt_crit = ev.id_fatt_crit WHERE ev.id_struttura=%s AND ev.id_tipo_accreditamento=%s AND ev.ID_evidenza < ".$_GET['id']." ORDER BY fc.ordine_fatt_crit, ev.cod_evidenza, ev.ordine_evidenza DESC LIMIT 1 ", GetSQLValueString($mystr_record_precedente, "int"),GetSQLValueString($myte_record_precedente, "int"));
    $record_precedente = mysqli_query($riskmanagement, $query_record_precedente) or die(mysqli_error($riskmanagement));
        createLog($_COOKIE['cod_operatore'], $query_record_precedente);

    $row_record_precedente = mysqli_fetch_assoc($record_precedente);
    $totalRows_record_precedente = mysqli_num_rows($record_precedente);

    echo "<div class=\"col-md-6\" align=\"right\">";
    if($totalRows_record_precedente >0){
        echo "<a href=\"edit_evidenza.php?id=".$row_record_precedente['ID_evidenza']."&te=".$_GET['te']."\"  class=\"btn btn-info btn-sm\">< requisito precedente</a>"; 
    }

mysqli_free_result($record_precedente);
```

---

```
$mystr_record_successivo = "-1";
if (isset($id_str)) {
  $mystr_record_successivo = $id_str;
}
$myte_record_successivo = "-1";
if (isset($sel_tipo_acc)) {
  $myte_record_successivo = $sel_tipo_acc;
}
//42320819($database_riskmanagement, $riskmanagement);
$query_record_successivo = sprintf("SELECT * FROM tev_Evidenze AS ev LEFT JOIN tev_Fatt_crit AS fc ON fc.ID_fatt_crit = ev.id_fatt_crit WHERE ev.id_struttura=%s AND ev.id_tipo_accreditamento=%s AND ev.ID_evidenza > ".$_GET['id']." ORDER BY fc.ordine_fatt_crit, ev.cod_evidenza, ev.ordine_evidenza ASC LIMIT 1 ", GetSQLValueString($mystr_record_successivo, "int"),GetSQLValueString($myte_record_successivo, "int"));
$record_successivo = mysqli_query($riskmanagement, $query_record_successivo) or die(mysqli_error($riskmanagement));
        createLog($_COOKIE['cod_operatore'], $query_record_successivo);

$row_record_successivo = mysqli_fetch_assoc($record_successivo);
$totalRows_record_successivo = mysqli_num_rows($record_successivo);

    if($totalRows_record_successivo >0){
        echo "&nbsp;";
        echo "<a href=\"edit_evidenza.php?id=".$row_record_successivo['ID_evidenza']."&te=".$_GET['te']."\" class=\"btn btn-info btn-sm\">requisito successivo ></a>";
    }
    echo "</div>";
mysqli_free_result($record_successivo);

}
?>
```

My intent is to allow the user to navigate smoothly between records.

Considering that this navigation takes place within a record or better.

Table with all records> within the single record

and here I should allow browsing

Comment: This is much too broad, you need to reduce your code and clarify your problem. Also you are open to SQL injection, you should search and learn about prepared statements.

Comment: @miken32 I would like to reduce the code, I found myself in front of this scenario, and I'm looking for where to start, my predecessor did this two select, and I wanted to tell the community which way to go

Comment: Yeah, I must agree with @miken32 that this is difficult to work out. No idea what those LEFT JOINs will do in those queries, they seems unnecessary, but are they?

Comment: @KIKOSoftware apparently not, in the sense, which seems to repeat the initial error that at some point instead of going from point 1 to 10, is not linear, even having raised all the part of the left joins

Comment: I don't get what you're saying. The problem for me is that I don't know what the fields in your database tables represent, nor do I know what's in the database. I would need to know that to work out what's happening.

Comment: `if($_GET['fe'] != "S"){ ...` what is this `...&fe=...` represents? Where `$id_str` is defined? If you could notice, `$_GET['te']` doesn't get changed from page to page, `echo ..."&te=".$_GET['te']."\"...`, is it expected? If so then why don't you just hardcode it in your query?

Comment: @RajdeepPaul besides the navigation problem, the problem is that I have two different categories where one has the document "A" and one has the document "B", the problem is that I skip the paging from category to category, and instead it should show me the pagination by category

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add any data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or data *of any kind* directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake. **DO NOT USE `sprintf` TO ADD DATA TO SQL QUERIES!**

Comment: Note: The [object-oriented interface to `mysqli`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.connections.php) is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface where missing a single `i` can cause trouble. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is largely an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and should not be used in new code.